# "activation of network connection failed" error for the all my wifi connections

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 10 with dual boot, and I can't get the any of my wifi connections to work.

When I run nmcli connection up (wifi-connection-name) it says
Error Connection activation failed No suitable device found for this connection

It doesn't show me any wifi networks in visible networks

I can't even update wifi drivers since I have no internet connection

Comment: For a start, please include the brand and model of WiFi adapter, and also do a search if someone else posted a question about the same model. Thanks. 

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (alone, no dual-boot) and a TOTOLINK Wireless Adapter.

It turns out that the kernel configuration is invalid (no idea why this happened while the distro was downloaded from ubuntu website). To fix this, reinstall `linux-headers` with the following single-line command ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361990/how-to-solve-kernel-configuration-is-invalid-issues/67156634#67156634)):

```sh
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then you may restart the system using `sudo reboot`. I didn't have to do that though: right after reinstalling `linux-headers` my adapter successfully connected to a WiFi network.

But sorry, the above command does need an Internet connection. In case of no Ethernet, you can connect a phone with your computer via USB, turn on mobile data and **USB Tethering** so that the phone acts as a network adapter.